# Linear Applied Algebra | Verify the vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Question:
[image]

My response:

[image]

Math has never been a strength, particularly proofs, so I would appreciate any and every help. I am just not sure if I am following a proper procedure for the above question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: hint: for the first one $1(1,1)+1(-1,-1) = (0,0)$  for the second one suppose $x(1,1)+y(1,0) = (0,0).$  find $x,y$ and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Another method which may be easier is simply proving that the first set of vectors is colinear, while the second set is not. A colinear set of vectors will not span $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, while a set of vectors which are not colinear with each other will span $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Two vectors are colinear if $ (a,b)=c(a,b)$ (they are constant multiples of one another)

Answer (score 0):

A third simple way to disprove that the first set of vectors spans $\mathbb{R}^2$ is by giving a counterexample like $(-1,1)$ ( which can't be 'built' by $q(1,1)+p(-1,-1)$). Hence those vectors don't span $\mathbb R^2$.

---

Regarding the proof for the second set I'd say your argument is fully valid and there is no need for changes.